# How to remove specific object from array on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

here is my first question:
i build project "to do list", each time when i add task i push to array object.
i would like to know how can i remove specific object from array "on-click".

*this is not the original project just example for know

```js
 
const input = document.querySelector(".input");
    const maindiv = document.querySelector(".maindiv");
    
    const list = []
    
    input.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (input.value && e.keyCode == 13) {
            const div = document.createElement("div")
            const title = document.createElement("h1")
            const btn = document.createElement("button")
    
            title.textContent = input.value
            btn.textContent = "remove"
    
            list.push({ text: input.value })
            btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                for(let i = 0; i < list.length;i++){
                    if(list[i].num == i){
                        list.splice(i,1)
    
                    }
                }
                e.target.parentElement.remove()
            })
            div.appendChild(title)
            div.appendChild(btn)
            maindiv.appendChild(div)
            document.body.appendChild(maindiv)    
        }
    })
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
    <input type="text" name="" class="input">
    <div class="maindiv"></div> 
    <script src="json.js"></script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Then when i have few div(array.object) i would like to remove exactly object from array on click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove from the array at the index.

You can get the index using [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

The example below is basic but should point you in the right direction. We start with an array of 10 values and use `findIndex` to get the index of the array value of `i-5`. Then, we use `splice` to remove it.

With your code, you could search on the `text` property of the object you are pushing to the array, or you could add some other identifier to make it easier to search.

```js
const arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr.push(`i-${i}`)
}

console.log(arr)

const index = arr.findIndex((a) => a === 'i-5')

if (index > -1) { // we found it
  arr.splice(index, 1)
}

console.log(arr)
```